# How can I recover an XCode project in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Recover XCode project](https://superuser.com/questions/42909/how-to-recover-xcode-project)

I have put my all xcodeproject in the desktop folder but accidently deleted the entire contents of the desktop!

Can anyone tell me how to recover the source code of .xcodeproj?

Comment: Did you empty the Trash as well?

Answer (score 2):

Is it in your Recycle Bin? If yes, congrats. If no, continue.

Do you have a Time Machine backup? If yes, congrats. If no continue.

Is it a UNIX filesys... oh wait, yes it *is* a UNIX filesystem. Well sorry to inform you this, but UNIX is quite thorough in making sure a file is deleted for good.

Not all is lost though, people have claimed good things about [VirtualLab](http://www.binarybiz.com/vlab/mac.html). It's not free, but they claim it will work. However chances are not as high as a Windows system, whose NTFS filesystem, for better or for worse, are less stringent in removing files completely when they are deleted.

Comment: You should have created a flowchart for this :)

Comment: @alex: well, some people were *complaining* about my wanton use of pictures...

Comment: I would add Source Control Management to your checklist...